# Error in number of decimal places with read.xlsx

Tags: r

I am trying to read in a dataset of coordinates in the British National grid system, using the read.xlsx command.
 This is the data:

> ```
> NORTHING  EASTING TOC ELEVATION   WELL ID
> 1194228.31  2254272.83  117.30  AA-1
> 1194227.81  2254193.90  114.91  AA-2
> 1194228.41  2254116.26  114.76  AA-3
> 1194229.37  2254039.57  112.81  AA-4
> 1194227.09  2253960.17  112.10  AA-5
> ```

and this is my code:

```
coordinates <- read.xlsx2("Coordinates.xlsx",sheetName = "Sheet1",
                      startRow = 1,endRow = 111, colIndex = c(1:4),
                colClasses = c("character","character","numeric","character"))
```

The problem is, my output looks like this:

`NORTHING EASTING TOC.ELEVATION WELL.ID
1  1194228 2254273        117.30    AA-1
2  1194228 2254194        114.91    AA-2
3  1194228 2254116        114.76    AA-3
4  1194229 2254040        112.81    AA-4
5  1194227 2253960        112.10    AA-5
6  1194227 2253880        110.98    AA-6`

The command is rounding up the horizontal and vertical coordinates, and while this is not a big issue, I'd like to be as exact as possible. Is there a workaround to this? I could not find anything in the options to the `colClasses` option either.

Comment: Why are you reading in the northings and eastings as characters?

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake on my part. I initially read them as numeric, but when I found it rounded up, I read them in as characters, hoping to convert them to numeric later. But when I did, I found that they ended up rounded anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue of how R is printing out the data (it is generally convenient *not* to give the full representation of floating-point data); you didn't actually lose any precision.

Illustrating with `read.table` rather than `read.xlsx` (we're going to end up in the same place). (If I read the data with `colClasses` specifying "character", I do get all of the digits displayed, but I also end up with a rather useless data frame if I want to do anything sensible with the northings and eastings variables ...)

```
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE,
text="
NORTHING  EASTING TOC.ELEVATION   WELL.ID
1194228.31  2254272.83  117.30  AA-1
1194227.81  2254193.90  114.91  AA-2
1194228.41  2254116.26  114.76  AA-3
1194229.37  2254039.57  112.81  AA-4
1194227.09  2253960.17  112.10  AA-5")
```

This is how R prints the data frame:

```
# NORTHING EASTING TOC.ELEVATION WELL.ID
# 1  1194228 2254273        117.30    AA-1
# 2  1194228 2254194        114.91    AA-2
# 3  1194228 2254116        114.76    AA-3
# 4  1194229 2254040        112.81    AA-4
# 5  1194227 2253960        112.10    AA-5
```

But it's still possible to see that all of the precision is still there ...

```
print(dat$NORTHING,digits=12)
## [1] 1194228.31 1194227.81 1194228.41 1194229.37 1194227.09
```

You could also `print(dat,digits=12)` or set `options(digits=12)` globally ...